# How to solve $a^x + bx = c$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is it possible to solve equation in form $$a^x + bx = c$$ algebraically, where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are given, $a, b, c \in \Bbb{N}$ and $x$ is unknown?

If it's solvable algebraically, how would you solve it?

If it's not solvable algebraically, could calculus be used?

Comment: If you want to solve it in the general case and not some particular ones this is not a precalculus question. Solving it requires some special functions called the r-Lambert functions.

Comment: You usually can't solve it algebraically, but see [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Comment: You either need Lambert's W-function or numerical methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the following [theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Example_1), which has a simple derivation by linear substitutions into the Lambert W function, the inverse function for $f(x)=xe^x$:

> The equation $p^{ax+b}=cx+d$ where $p>0$ and $c,a\ne0$ yields the solution $$x = -\frac{W(-\frac{a\ln p}{c}\,p^{b-\frac{a d}{c}})}{a\ln p} - \frac{d}{c}.$$

Substituting $p\mapsto a$, $a\mapsto1$, $b\mapsto 0$, $c\mapsto-b$, $d\mapsto c$ from your statement gives the solution

$$x = \frac cb-\frac{W(\frac{\ln a}b\,a^{\frac cb})}{\ln a}.$$

Note that since $f(x)=xe^x$ is not injective, the $W$ function actually has several branches, depending on the values of the parameters.